# Xcode: New file not being placed in workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Not sure why this started happening; I didn't change anything and I didn't update Xcode.

All of a sudden, when I add a new file (by any route), the files do not end up in my workspace, and instead are placed in a folder inside my project directory. For example, if I add a new UIViewController, it is placed into a folder in my project directory named "ective-C". If I add a .xib file, it is placed in the project directory in a folder named "emplate". It seems like the folders are being created based on the file type, but that a portion of the folder name is being cut off. This whole thing is weird because, why are the new files being placed into a random folder at all? And on top of that, why are they not immediately in my workspace? I have to go to the newly created folder, move them out of it, delete the folder, and drag/drop the files into my workspace.

Has anyone else dealt with this?

Comment: You can drag your .xib in  in folder of "ective-C". and in future select that folder then add a file

Comment: @VikasRajput I think you're missing the point of the question. I don't want the files to go into these folders at all. It never used to happen, and started to do so randomly. What you are suggesting is how I've been getting around it. Please re-read the question.